# Нарисовать Button при клике на окно WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Я хочу сделать приложение : юзер кликает и зажимает мышку, а когда он её отпускает, рисуется `Button` у которого левый верхний угол это координаты клика (событие `MouseDown`), а правый нижний - координаты места где пользователь отпустил кнопку мыши (событие `MouseUp`). Вот код для `MouseDown`:

```
private void MainWindow_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    StartPoint = e.GetPosition(this);
    //Свойство StartPoint объявляется сверху таким образом
    //private System.Windows.Point StartPoint { get; set; }
}
```

Вот код для `MouseUp`:

```
private void MainWindow_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
     EndPoint = e.GetPosition(this);
     //Свойство EndPoint объявляется сверху таким образом
     //private System.Windows.Point EndPoint { get; set; }

     Button temp = new Button();
     temp.Margin = new Thickness(StartPoint.X, StartPoint.Y, EndPoint.X, EndPoint.Y);
     temp.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
     temp.Content = "Do not click me!";

     mainGrid.Children.Add(temp);
}
```

Это не работает, кнопки рисуются слишком большими или вообще не рисуются. Что я делаю не так и как сделать так, чтобы это заработало?

Comment: Зачем тебе EndPoint? Убери это. В Margin оставь StartPoint, а остальное в 0. Задай `VerticalAlighnment` как `Top` и `HorizontalAlighnment` как `Left`. Так же установи нужный размер кнопки. Width - ширина, Height - высота (в пикселях).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Координаты надо считать для того контрола, куда вкладываете кнопку. К данном случае для грида.
2. Маргин справа и снизу - это не координаты, это расстояние от края контрола до края кнопки (в вашем случае)

Немного переписал ваш код

```
private void MainWindow_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    StartPoint = e.GetPosition(mainGrid);
    //Свойство StartPoint объявляется сверху таким образом
    //private System.Windows.Point StartPoint { get; set; }
}

private void MainWindow_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    EndPoint = e.GetPosition(mainGrid);
    //Свойство EndPoint объявляется сверху таким образом
    //private System.Windows.Point EndPoint { get; set; }           

    Button temp = new Button();
    temp.Margin = new Thickness(StartPoint.X, StartPoint.Y, mainGrid.ActualWidth - EndPoint.X, mainGrid.ActualHeight - EndPoint.Y);
    temp.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
    temp.Content = "Do not click me!";

    mainGrid.Children.Add(temp);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, заработало!

Answer (score 2):

Для того, чтобы располагать контролы по абсолютным координатам, правильно использовать `Canvas`, он для этого специально предназначен. Поэтому я бы написал так:

XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Canvas MouseLeftButtonDown="OnCanvasLeftMouseDown" Background="Transparent"/>
</Grid>
```

Code-behind:

```
void OnCanvasLeftMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs eDown)
{
    var canvas = (Canvas)sender;
    var startPos = eDown.GetPosition(canvas);
    canvas.MouseLeftButtonUp += OnUp;
    void OnUp(object _, MouseButtonEventArgs eUp) // захватим позицию начала
    {
        canvas.MouseLeftButtonUp -= OnUp;
        var endPos = eUp.GetPosition(canvas);
        var button = new Button()
        {
            Content = "Do not click me!",
            Width = Math.Abs(endPos.X - startPos.X),
            Height = Math.Abs(endPos.Y - startPos.Y)
        };
        Canvas.SetLeft(button, Math.Min(startPos.X, endPos.X));
        Canvas.SetTop(button, Math.Min(startPos.Y, endPos.Y));
        canvas.Children.Add(button);
    }
}
```

---

С подачи @tym32167, более строгий вариант:

```
void OnCanvasLeftMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs eDown)
{
    var canvas = (Canvas)sender;
    var startPos = eDown.GetPosition(canvas);
    canvas.MouseLeftButtonUp += OnUp;
    canvas.Unloaded += Unsubscribe;
    Mouse.Capture(canvas);

    void OnUp(object _, MouseButtonEventArgs eUp) // захватим позицию начала
    {
        Mouse.Capture(null);
        Unsubscribe(_, eUp);
        var endPos = eUp.GetPosition(canvas);
        if (!canvas.IsMouseOver)
            return;
        var button = new Button()
        {
            Content = "Do not click me!",
            Width = Math.Abs(endPos.X - startPos.X),
            Height = Math.Abs(endPos.Y - startPos.Y)
        };
        Canvas.SetLeft(button, Math.Min(startPos.X, endPos.X));
        Canvas.SetTop(button, Math.Min(startPos.Y, endPos.Y));
        canvas.Children.Add(button);
    }

    void Unsubscribe(object _, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        canvas.MouseLeftButtonUp -= OnUp;
        canvas.Unloaded -= Unsubscribe;
    }
}
```

Добавлен захват мыши, чтобы отпускание её происходило в том же контексте. Также добавлена подписка на выгрузку `Canvas`'а, на случай, если логика UI выгрузит его до отпускания мыши.

Comment: Канвас - хорошо. Новый синтаксис - хорошо. Подписка/отписка на событие в событии - плохо. Вы же понимаете, что мышка может быть нажата в нашем контроле и отжата в другом. Чтобы такого избежать, в вашем случае надо захватывать мышку при нажатии и отпускать при отжатии кнопки ( ```canvas.CaptureMouse(); / canvas.ReleaseMouseCapture();``` )

Comment: @tym32167: Ещё неплохо бы подписаться на `Unloaded`, потому что контрол может исчезнуть.

Comment: Ну, мне больше всего не понравилась динамическая подписка/отписка. Имел столько с этим проблем, что теперь такой код заставляет меня ёжиться и чувствовать дискомфорт :)

Comment: @tym32167: Кстати, в вашем варианте по идее тоже нужно проверять, над каким контролом произошло нажатие и отпускание мыши. Например, `mainGrid` может оказаться размером не на всё окно. Подписка на `MouseDown` у `mainGrid`, а не у всего окна, выглядит чище.

Comment: @tym32167: Вроде с динамической подпиской проблем особых не было, хотя, конечно, если UI-элемент между нажатием и отпусканием мыши может «уйти», приходится программировать очень аккуратно.

Comment: В моем примере да, есть тоже пробелы, я просто пытался пофиксить проблему с расчетом координат, не обращая внимание на остальное. Сорри, что к вам привязался, просто эти подписки меня напрягли :)

Answer (score 0):

```
private void Grid_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
    Mouse.Capture(sender as IInputElement);
}

private void Grid_PreviewMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) {

    Point upPoint = e.GetPosition(sender as Grid);

    if (upPoint.X < 0 || upPoint.X > mainGrid.ActualWidth ||
            upPoint.Y < 0 || upPoint.Y > mainGrid.ActualHeight)
        return;

    Mouse.Capture(null);

    Button button = new Button();
    button.Margin = new Thickness(upPoint.X, upPoint.Y, 0, 0);
    button.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
    button.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
    button.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
    button.Content = "Do not click me!";
    button.Width = 120;
    button.Height = 20;
    mainGrid.Children.Add(button);
}
```